# How to sort the double bar using ggplot in r?

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am learning r and I have problem with sorting the double bar in ascending or descending order and I want to set the legend just on the top of the plot with two color represent respectively with one row and two columns like for example:

The title `Time`

box color `Breakfast`    box color `Dinner`

And the plot here

Here is my dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner"), levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner")),
  class = c("a","a","b","b","c","a","b","b","c","c","c","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"))
```

And here is my code to make change:

```
dat %>% 
  filter(time %in% c("Breakfast", "Dinner")) %>%
  droplevels %>%
  count(time, class) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = prop, fill = time, label = scales::percent(prop))) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = 0.5, size = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  coord_flip()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the legend title above the legend key, requires a little additional adjustments to the theme and guides.

```
dat %>% 
  filter(time %in% c("Breakfast", "Dinner")) %>%
  droplevels %>%
  count(time, class) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = class, y = prop, fill = time, label = scales::percent(prop))) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = 0.5, size = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.direction="vertical", legend.title=element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Time", nrow = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should be close to what you are asking, feel free to ask more

Resources consulted during the answer: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-legend-easy-steps-to-change-the-position-and-the-appearance-of-a-graph-legend-in-r-software

Using part of the answer you can look further into https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Lunch","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner","Dinner"), levels=c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner")),
  class = c("a","a","b","b","c","a","b","b","c","c","c","a","a","b","b","b","c","c"))


dat %>% 
  filter(time %in% c("Breakfast", "Dinner")) %>%
  droplevels %>%
  count(time, class) %>% 
  group_by(time) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(class,prop), y = prop, fill = time, label = scales::percent(prop))) +
  geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = 0.5, size = 3) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "class",fill = "Time") +
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.direction="vertical", legend.title=element_text(hjust = 0.5,face = "bold",size = 12))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: For the legend label like Breakfast and Dinner if I want to add specific text instead of them both what should I use?

Comment: You can change the data before ggplot to display whatever you need

Comment: Can you edit a little bit on your answer? For the label ```time``` also I cannot adjust the size and I want the font a bit stronger like bold

Comment: Also I want to change the text label in the legend like Breakfast and Dinner to our desire text we want. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand

Comment: I wanna ask you that Is there a way to edit  the text in the legend label? I want that in the legend  ```Time``` there are ```Breakfast``` and ```Dinner``` I want to add additional percentage to specify it like ```Breakfast (40%)``` for example